# How create different cookies for one application that runs in iframe in different websites for every website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-config

My MVC 4 web application is running in iframe and will run in different websites.

Now I have the problem that when I open the application in different client websites but in the same browser I get the same data because the app already has the cookie of my app created on first open.

I need to have different cookies for different clients and I don't want to use `cookieless=true` because it causes some other issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create cookies on login (or appropriate point) for each client with clientName to make it unique.

Comment: on start I'm creating sessions and this sessions are stored in browser as cookies when I open the application in another domain browser see takes these cookies and my app not creating new session  how solve this

Comment: I am struggling to understand your situation clearly, can you add some code? I am not sure why you said "I'm creating sessions"? May be someone else would understand and respond.

Comment: Let me explain again I have application that we using in iframe in our different partners websites, the application located in one domain, in iframe we are getting some info from partner website like their id and something else and storing sessions and depending of partner the application returning data can be different. so the problem is  that even if our application is running in different websites it has one domain and it is the same application and the cookie that it stores in browser is same so when I'm trying to open the second clients website in the same browser in the other tabs

Comment: it takes session cookies and see that the application already has session and not creates the new one  and my application getting wrong data from these sessions stores the same data for anotherpartner

Comment: Oh ok now i see. You need the separate session to be created for each client, challenge is since your app is hosted in an iframe, the session is shared between clients. I am afraid I do not have any solution to offer at this time. May be our conversation will help other to understand and offer help :)